# How can i clear my Dictionary data . It store data and return same message every time

Tags: swift, dictionary

This function store first value and return the same message.

I tried this :

FileManager.default.clearTmpDirectory()

```
       let resultt:NSDictionary = dict! as NSDictionary
            //let topup = resultt.value(forKeyPath: "Body.QR_TopupResponse.QR_TopupResult") as! String
            func getdata () -> String{
                guard let body = resultt["Body"] as? [String: Any] else {
                    // Failed to find body, return empty string
                    return ""
                }
                guard let response = body["QR_TopResponse"] as? [String: Any] else {
                    return ""
                }
                guard let result = response["QR_ToResult"] as? String else {
                    return ""
                }
                return result
            }
            print(getdata())

  self.presentAlert(withTitle: "", message: getdata())

 or  .. 
  var ftsm = resultsm.value(forKeyPath: 
"Body.QR_TOPResponse.QR_TOPResult") as! String

  // How to remove keypath.
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear your dictionary data, You should try:

```
myDictionary.removeAll()
```

or you can also try :
`removeAllObjects` method of `NSMutableDictionary` which is derived from NSDictionary

```
[myDictionary removeAllObjects];
[myDictionary release];
myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

**As a result of that**, calling `-removeAllObjects` will empty the dictionary and release all of the contained objects.

Comment: Not working. It stores data and prints the same message

Comment: var ftsm = resultsm.value(forKeyPath: "Body.QR_FundTransferResponse.QR_FundTransferResult") as! String            
                                                                                                                  
        I want to remove all object from keyPath.